# Django REST framework save()

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

When deserializing data with keyword argument `many=True`

```
serialized = MySerializer(data=request.data, many=True)
```

and then call `.save()`, I wonder if it is performing one database operation, or just iterating the list of sub-data, and perform `create()` and `update()` individually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a place where I always recommend [looking at the code itself](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/4bca062df65454d0a9fbfc536a7b2510ddb4c6b3/rest_framework/serializers.py#L469-L617) as it will always provide the most up-to-date answer. Currently the default `create` code for a `ListSerializer` is

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    return [
        self.child.create(attrs) for attrs in validated_data
    ]
```

The answer is that it will manually call `create` for each object, which means that it is not performing a bulk insert. Part of this comes from the fact that Django REST Framework is *not designed to work efficiently* with large amounts of data, with the exception of displaying it. It also [does not support bulk updates](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/4bca062df65454d0a9fbfc536a7b2510ddb4c6b3/rest_framework/serializers.py#L565-L572) by default.

---

You can find more information on [the default bulk creation in the documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#customizing-multiple-create), as well as help on [creating your own bulk update methods as well](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#customizing-multiple-update). This will require you to create your own custom `ListSerializer` with your own `create` and `update` methods that do what you are looking for. Keep in mind that a `ListSerializer` is what Django REST Framework internally wraps your `many=True` serializer with, which you can see by calling `repr(serializer)` where `serializer` is your serializer that you have initialized with `many=True`.

---

In the past, bulk updates have been handled by a third-party package [called Django REST Framework Bulk](https://github.com/miki725/django-rest-framework-bulk/). While the package works with DRF 2.x, it is [in the process of being updated for 3.0](https://github.com/miki725/django-rest-framework-bulk/issues/23). There is a pull request that is currently under review for adding 3.0 support, so I would expect there to be a new release soon that adds support.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation, it will make one call per object in the collection, but you can override this behaviour:

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#customizing-multiple-create